# Jquery selector for laravel array Validation errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I tried to display the Laravel 5.5 Ajax error Validation using jQuery  automatically,

When for single field it was work, to use following code:

```
$.each(response.errors, function (key, value) {
    el.find('input[name="'+key+'"] , select[name="'+key+'"] , textarea[name="'+key+'"]').parent().append('<div class="error right-align pink-text text-mute">'+value+'</div>');
});
```

The code above will append an error message to each element based on selector.

But if I use array field, for example `<input type="text" name="start_date[]" />`
Then I got following error validation:

```
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"start_date.0":["The start_date.0 field is required when availability is 0."],"start_date.1":["The start_date.1 field is required."],"end_date.0":["The end_date.0 field is required."],"end_date.1":["The end_date.1 field is required."]}}
```

So my javascript couldn't find the elements **start_date.0**

How to select the element using jQuery with that response ? **(start_date.0 , start_date.1)**

Comment: Did you check my answer I think you want to get value of `start_date.0` in `errors` ?

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Comment: Yes, See my answer bellow

Answer (score 1):

thanks for all the answer, I end this problem by using id attribute, so my html tag should be like this `<input type="text" id="start_date.0" name="start_date[]" />`

Since jquery doesn't allow dot "." pattern in selector, My selector should be like this 
`el.find('input[id="select_date.0"]')`

So My code  should be:

```
$.each(response.errors, function (key, value) {
    el.find('input[id="'+key+'"],input[name="'+key+'"] , select[name="'+key+'"] , textarea[name="'+key+'"]').parent().append('<div class="error right-align pink-text text-mute">'+value+'</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `errors['start_date.0']` instead `errors.start_date.0`

```js
var myObj  = {"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"start_date.0":["The start_date.0 field is required when availability is 0."],"start_date.1":["The start_date.1 field is required."],"end_date.0":["The end_date.0 field is required."],"end_date.1":["The end_date.1 field is required."]}};

console.log(myObj.errors['start_date.0']);
```

Using `start_date.0` it tries to get element `0` in object `start_date`, but you have this `start_date.0` as element of `errors` so use bracket `[ ]` to treat `start_date.0` as element of `errors`

```js
var response = {"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"start_date.0":["The start_date.0 field is required when availability is 0."],"start_date.1":["The start_date.1 field is required."],"end_date.0":["The end_date.0 field is required."],"end_date.1":["The end_date.1 field is required."],"dob":["Date of birth is required."]}};

$.each(response.errors, function (key, value) {
  var name = $("input[name='"+key+"']");
  if(key.indexOf(".") != -1){
    var arr = key.split(".");
    name = $("input[name='"+arr[0]+"[]']:eq("+arr[1]+")");
  }
  name.parent().append('<div class="error right-align pink-text text-mute">'+value[0]+'</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type="text" name="start_date[]" value=""></div>
<div><input type="text" name="start_date[]" value=""></div>
<div><input type="text" name="end_date[]" value=""></div>
<div><input type="text" name="end_date[]" value=""></div>
<div><input type="text" name="dob" value=""></div>
```

Comment: will it be possible to append it using jquery if the name is start_date[] ?

Comment: I am  not getting you . append means you want to convert `start_date[0]` to `start_date.0` ?

Comment: yes .. the OP wants to append it using `el.find('input[name="'+key+'"] `

Comment: @Niladri :  he said `couldn't find the elements start_date.0` and `How to select the element using jQuery with that response ? (start_date.0 , start_date.1)` , I think I given the answer for the same

Comment: @user2486 I have no problem to get the error message , my problem is
how to select the element  `el.find('input[name="start_date.0"]')`

Comment: @dennysaputra 
: Check second snippet as you want

Answer (score -1):

```
error: function(data){
    var response = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
    var errorString = '<ul style="list-style: none;">';
    $.each( response.errors, function( key, value) {
       errorString += '<li><small>' + value + '</small></li>';
    });
    errorString += '</ul>';

    $("#errors").html(errorString);
}
```